# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in ubuntu

Tags: java

I am using `jdk1.8.0_25`, and when I check the version of Java with the following command:

```
java -version
```

it outputs the following

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Please solve my problem.

Comment: Well you're clearly *not* using JDK 1.8.0_25 when you run `java -version`... we can't tell why you think you are.

Comment: If an answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error, and while the java version correctly set to 8, my JAVA_HOME env var was still set to 7.

Executing this fixed it for me:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have more than one java JDK installed. Try to check that by

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `/>which java` to determine where the `java` command is coming from on the path.

You either need to change to put jdk 1.8 on the path or use the fully qualified path to the `java` executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can install several different java versions on to your system. You can set the default using the update-alternatives command.

Here is a solution to a similiar problem, which is maybe of use for you:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version