# Java + Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, centos

Basic configurations:

Docker container for My PHP instance, I installed Centos and inside java, then Selenium but when I try to start it, it gives me an error.

```
[root@6f0958965698 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
```

> CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

```
[root@6f0958965698 ~]# java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

```
[root@6f0958965698 ~]# java -version
```

> java version "1.7.0_191" / OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.15.4.el7_5-x86_64 u191-b01)/ OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.191-b01, mixed mode)

1. I tried first with the version http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.9/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar
2. and then with: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.2/selenium-server-standalone-3.2.0.jar

Same mistake.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like your using Open JDK. Install oracle-jdk and try

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541629/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception in thread *main* `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` is thrown because the jar is compiled with higher version of Java and trying to run with lower version.

Please refer to this answer: [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/9481454)

Ex:
Compiled with JDK 1.8
But you run it JDK 1.7, so this throws the exception.

Just update the java version to JDK 1.8 in your container and run again.

Comment: @OrazioD'Arrigo I’m new to Stack-over I saw this question and I know the answer so answered it.. :)